Graph does not plot the correct time series
I am trying to plot the concentration of black carbon from 16:00 on August 6, 2024 to 12:30 on August 7, 2024. At the moment, my graph starts from 0:00 on August 7, 2024 and runs until midnight on August 6, 2024.
I have the code:
Air_Filter_384 = pd.read_csv("384_20240806_edited.csv")

# Retrieve Time and convert to date-time format
Air_Filter_384_DateTime = pd.to_datetime(Air_Filter_384['Time'])

# Retrieve Black Carbon Concentrations, converting ng/m^3 to mg/m^3
Air_Filter_384_BC = Air_Filter_384['BC'] / 1_000_000

plt.plot(
    Air_Filter_384_DateTime,
    Air_Filter_384_BC,
    marker='o',
    label='Filter 384')

For the time, it starts at 16:00 on August 6, 2024 and ends at 12:30 on August 7, 2024. At the moment, my graph starts from 0:00 on August 7, 2024 and runs until midnight on August 6, 2024. How do I make my graph start at 16:00 on August 6 and end at 12:30 on August 7?
Graph output

Please provide some example data. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples and more broadly, [mre]. It also wouldn't hurt to add the output (image) you're currently getting.

Presumably there is a date field in addition to the time field so you need to use them together
